# How to calculate kinetic friction coefficient given velocity and height?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, velocity, free-body-diagram

The problem I am dealing with is about an object sliding down a ramp. I am only given the height of the top of the ramp to the floor, initial and final velocity, and weight of the object (in lbs). How do I calculate the coefficient of kinetic friction with only this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conservation of energy (or work-kinetic energy theorem). You know the work by kinetic friction is $W=-\mu_k N d$ where $N$ is the normal force (which you must find using the dimensions of the incline) and $d$ is the length of the incline.

You're likely given enough information to find the angle the incline makes with the horizontal (which is required to find $N$).

Comment: We are only given the highest point of the ramp and the lowest point of the ramp. Not the length of the hypotenuse or the other side.

Comment: can you show me the problem as it's written?

Comment: I was supposed to find the ratio of two coefficient so I realized that N and d don't matter because in both scenarios, they are equal to each other (as only the final velocities are different in the entire problem). Thank you so much for your help! Your tip on the conservation of energy really helped and I arrived at a solution :)

Comment: no worries, glad to help. whenever you're working with speeds values, heights, etc, conservation of energy/work-KE theorem should be something to consider.